# how should I express the fact that someone is here with me on vacation

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I don't know the natural way of saying "someone is visiting me and he/she is on vacation right now".

There's some ambiguity in "this person is visiting me" because it can be interpreted as the person is not here yet and is going to visit me soon. What I want to express is that this person is visiting me and he/she is here with me already. So does the following sentence make sense?

> my girlfriend is visiting me from Canada and she just came last week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you suggest otherwise the form "She is visiting me" would be understood to mean "she is visiting me now".

So what you write makes sense, but it is a bit redundant. You could just say

> My girlfriend arrived from Canada last week.

and it implies that she is here now, or

> My Canadian girlfriend is visiting me now.

If you use the redundant phrase, then note that this will emphasise the redundancy.

> My girlfriend is visiting me from Canada and she just came last week

This emphasises the fact that she came *last week*. You would use this to tell somebody who would doubt that she came "last week".

> Please Mr immigration officer, my girlfriend is only visiting me. She isn't staying here permanently. She arrived from Canada just last week, and she is booked on the flight back to Canada on Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

What if you say: "My girlfriend from Canada is on a visit to me". Or "My girlfriend is here on a visit from Canada", "My girlfriend is here on a visit", "...is on a visit at my place".